# How to show table section titles in iOS 6?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I was able to show titles in table sections in iOS 7, but the text does not appear in iOS 6. I understand that you can either use titles or custom header views, but not both at the same time, so I made sure not to define `tableView:viewForHeaderInSection:`.

[image][image]

This is the relevant code. This is a subclass of UIViewController, not UITableViewController. I needed a sticky table header, so I had to do custom composition of the table view.

```
- (void)loadView
{
    [super loadView];

    // "width" and "height" properties are convenience methods
    // that I defined in a UIView category.
    self.tableView = [[UITableView alloc]
        initWithFrame:CGRectMake(
            0.0,
            SEARCH_BAR_HEIGHT + self.avatarCollectionView.height,
            self.view.width,
            self.view.height - (SEARCH_BAR_HEIGHT + self.avatarCollectionView.height)
        )
        style:UITableViewStylePlain
    ];
    [self.view addSubview:self.tableView];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.tableView.delegate = self;
    self.tableView.dataSource = self;
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // displayAlphabet is an NSMutableArray of one character strings.
    // It is a subset of the entire alphabet. For example, it can be:
    // @[@"A", @"B", @"C", @"E", @"X", @"Z"]
    return self.displayAlphabet.count;
}

- (NSString*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [self.displayAlphabet objectAtIndex:section];
}

- (NSArray*)sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return self.displayAlphabet;
}
```

How do I get the title text to appear in iOS 6?

Comment: what is the items data type for self.displayAlphabet ?

Comment: Have you made sure to return a nonzero height for `tableView:heightForHeaderInSection:`, or set the `sectionHeaderHeight` property on the table view?

Comment: how to get alphabetical whether it store locally or fetch from db/some where

Comment: @Ramshad NSMutableArray

Comment: write NSLog(@""); inside your table delegates and make sure the values are returned as expected.

Comment: @smileyborg , I tried both those methods to set the header height to a test value of 50.0. All it did was make the header very thick. There is still no text inside the header iOS 6.

Comment: Assuming the line `return [self.displayAlphabet objectAtIndex:section];` works correctly (e.g. returns a string that's not empty or nil) and assuming you have not implemented `tableView:viewForHeaderInSection:` (and it is not being implemented in any superclass), then I'm not sure what's going on. You might as well just setup a custom view (UILabel) and return that as the view for the section headers (in addition to returning whatever height is appropriate).

Comment: Yes, I'd be interested in what you see if you NSLog `[self.displayAlphabet objectAtIndex:section]` in `-tableView:titleForHeaderInSection:`.

Answer (score 4):

You must be having some bug as the order of your method call is not so clear. So here is a simple step guide.

Declare a  `NSArray *titleArray` to hold your titles. In `viewDidLoad` initialize your table as well as your title array.

```
tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height) style:UITableViewStylePlain];
tableView.delegate         = self;
tableView.dataSource       = self;
tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
tableView.autoresizingMask = (UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight);
[self.view addSubview:tableView];
```

`titleArray = @[@"A", @"B", @"C", @"E", @"X", @"Z"];`

Now, few delegate method as,

```
-(NSInteger) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 3;
}

- (NSString*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [titleArray objectAtIndex:section];
}

- (NSArray*)sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
   return titleArray;
}
```

And here is the Output.

iOS6 :

[image: iOS6 Screen Shot]

ioS7 :

[image: ios7 screen Shot]

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

The `UILocalizedIndexedCollation` class is a convenience for organizing, sorting, and localizing the data for a table view that has a section index. The table view’s data source then uses the collation object to provide the table view with input for section titles and section index titles.

**Apple Sample App**

[SimpleIndexedTableView](https://github.com/iDevAndroid/SimpleIndexedTableView)

Referance Doc: [Apple Inc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Reference/UILocalizedIndexedCollation_Class/UILocalizedIndexedCollation.html)

[image]

[image]

```
@property (nonatomic) NSMutableArray *sectionsArray;
@property (nonatomic) UILocalizedIndexedCollation *collation;

-(void)viewDidLoad{

 [self configureSections];
 [self.tableView reloadData];
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    // The number of sections is the same as the number of titles in the collation.
    return [[self.collation sectionTitles] count];
}


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Check to see whether the normal table or search results table is being displayed and return the count from the appropriate array

    NSArray *timeZonesInSection = (self.sectionsArray)[section];

    NSLog(@"count tableview %d",timeZonesInSection.count);

    return [timeZonesInSection count];

}

/*
 Section-related methods: Retrieve the section titles and section index titles from the collation.
 */

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [self.collation sectionTitles][section];
}


- (NSArray *)sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return [self.collation sectionIndexTitles];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView sectionForSectionIndexTitle:(NSString *)title atIndex:(NSInteger)index {
    return [self.collation sectionForSectionIndexTitleAtIndex:index];
}


- (void)configureSections {


    // Get the current collation and keep a reference to it.
    self.collation = [UILocalizedIndexedCollation currentCollation];

    NSInteger index, sectionTitlesCount = [[self.collation sectionTitles] count];

    NSMutableArray *newSectionsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:sectionTitlesCount];

    // Set up the sections array: elements are mutable arrays that will contain the time zones for that section.
    for (index = 0; index < sectionTitlesCount; index++) {
        NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        [newSectionsArray addObject:array];
    }


    self.sectionsArray = newSectionsArray;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code in UITableView class where you want to show data -:

```
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section

{
NSString *title = nil;
switch (section) 
{
    case section1:
        title= @"First";
        break;
    case section2:
        title= @"Second";
        break;
    case section3:
        title = @"Third";
        break;
    default:
        break;
}

return title;
```

}

```
- (UIView *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

{

```
//    CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame];
    UIView* headerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,100, 320, 44.0)];
UILabel *headerLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(15.0, -28.0, 300.0, 90.0)];
headerLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
headerLabel.opaque = NO;
headerLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:15];
headerLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    //headerView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleToFill;

    // Add the label
    switch (section)
    {
        case section1:
        {                
            headerLabel.text = @"First";

            [headerView addSubview: headerLabel];
            break;
        }
        case section2:
        {                
            headerLabel.text = @"Second";

            [headerView addSubview: headerLabel];
            break;
        }

        case section3:
        {
            headerLabel.text = @"Third";

            [headerView addSubview: headerLabel];
            break;
        }


        default:
            break;
    }


    // Return the headerView
```

return headerView;;
}